# Java Calculating average from users input

Tags: java, arrays, average

I have a problem with my code.Please help me to solve it. Program should quit and return average when q is entered. If you enter 5 numbers it is working fine. The array size should be 20. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{

public static void main(String[] args){

int x;

int count=0;
char q= 'q'; 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] array = new int[5];
System.out.print("You have entered 0 numbers, please enter a number or q to quit:" );

while (input.hasNextInt()){

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{

    array[i] = input.next();

    count++;
    System.out.print("You have entered " +count+ " numbers, please enter a number or q to quit:" );
    }
}

System.out.println("Average is " + Average(array));
}



public static int Average(int[] array) {
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
sum += array[i];
return sum / array.length;
}

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You're calling `input.hasNextInt()`. Is `q` an integer?

Comment: that is the problem, I know q is not an integer but to make it all work I have no idea. Program should quiut and return average when q is entered.

Comment: I also want to add that if put exact 5 integers the code will run and give average but if more or less 5 I get error

Comment: you should call while(input.hasNext()) and then check if entered input is type of char or int. If found char then quit.

Comment: So then use if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Use List instead of array. Check if input is q print the average and return system.exit(0)

Answer (score 0):

You should check input.hasNextInt() before each input.nextInt().

Answer (score 0):

You're using a compound loop which is negating the ability to break out of the first/outter loop.

You should consolidate the two loops into a single loop, looking for two escape conditions, either the user presses `q` or they enter 5 numbers...

Because you're expecting mixed input, you need to convert the input manually to an int....

```
String line = null;
// Loop until count >= 5 or the user inputs "q"
while (count < array.length && !(line = input.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
    try {
        // Convert the input to an int...
        int value = Integer.parseInt(line);
        array[count] = value;
        count++;
        System.out.print("You have entered " + count + " array, please enter a number or q to quit:");
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        System.out.println(line + " is not an int value...");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but this code is too complicated for me now, this is just second assignment and the code should be as simple as possible.

Comment: What parts are having problems with?

Comment: The program can crash if non interger value is entered, it is fine. So I guess I don't need to use catch and everything that follows?

Comment: I tried to use your code but average is not working anymore. can you please tell how to make it work? For example user inputs 6 number and then enters q and it should return average.

Comment: Did you call your average method after the while loop?

Comment: Yes. It is part of assignment to use method that calculates average.

Comment: if there is other way instead of using while loop just let me know. I just tried it this way. example of running code should be like this:

Comment: You have entered 4 numbers, please enter a number or q to quit: q
The display might be:

The average is: 2.5

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the while-loop but with the average algorithm. For example, if I enter 1, 1, 1, q. I would expect an average of 1, but your method would return 0.6... Yests because you're not taking into account the number of numbers I entered and are simply using array.length. For example, 3 / 5 = 0.6.  You need so e way to determine how many numbers the user has entered...